# Swift Compiler Error: “Expression too complex” on a mathematical equation

Tags: swift

When I add this equation

```
colViewHeight = (colItemSize * CGFloat(Counts)) + (colLineSpace * 
CGFloat(Counts)) + (colViewTopSpace+colViewBottomSpace) as CGFloat
```

I get the below mentioned error.

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

How to solve this issue? I am using xcode 10.01 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into multiple subexpressions and check if type casting is working fine

Such as:

```
let first = (colItemSize * CGFloat(Counts))
let second = (colViewTopSpace + colViewBottomSpace) as CGFloat

colViewHeight = first + second
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the redundant bridge cast `as CGFloat` and the redundant parentheses

```
colViewHeight = colItemSize * CGFloat(Counts) + colLineSpace * CGFloat(Counts) + colViewTopSpace + colViewBottomSpace
```